# How to show the vertical scale of marginal histogram in a jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

In Seaborn jointplot, the marginal histograms do not show the y axis values. How can I get these values? The documentation doesn't show any arguments to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to work more on the matplotlib side of things. If you just want to get the limits of the axis, you can use `get_ylim`. The handle for those histograms are `ax_marg_x` and `ax_marg_y`.

```
g = sns.jointplot(...)
g.ax_marg_x.get_ylim()
```

You can also make the tick labels visible using `set_visible` on the tick labels:

```
for tick in g.ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels():
    tick.set_visible(True)
```

[image]

You can also create your own tick labels with `set_yticklabels`.