# Show the yticks in the marginal plots of seaborn.JointGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I need to show the yticks in the marginal distribution of a Seaborn.jointgrid plot, but it doesn't seem simple.

Here is an example of a code taken from the Seaborn documentation:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import bumpy as np
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, color="m")
_ = g.ax_marg_x.hist(tips["total_bill"], color="b", alpha=.6,
                      bins=np.arange(0, 60, 5))
_ = g.ax_marg_y.hist(tips["tip"], color="r", alpha=.6,
                      orientation="horizontal",
                      bins=np.arange(0, 12, 1))
```

I would like to add the yaxis and its values to the marginal plots. I can plot the yaxis using:

```
sns.despine(ax=g.ax_marg_x)
sns.despine(ax=g.ax_marg_y)
```

But it doesn't contain any values or ticks. I have tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798371/how-to-show-the-vertical-scale-of-marginal-histogram-in-seaborn-jointplot) but it just doesn't do anything.

Here is the plot given by the code

[image]

Comment: As of seaborn 0.12.1, you can also call `sns.JointGrid(marginal_ticks=True)` which does the same as the 6 lines of code starting with `g.ax_marg` in @JohanC's answer. If you want to adjust the looks of the ticks, you need to dig further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axes of the marginal plots are ['shared'](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) with the main plot. Default, they don't get tick labels. To turn the tick labels on again, [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) has options such as `labelleft=True` and `labelbottom=True`.

When setting ticks for the histogram values, it can be handy to also set gridlines. The default number of gridlines might be too low, they can be increased with a [tick locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html). Also, the default linestyle might be too heavy. Linestyle, color and thickness can be adapted via `grid()`

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, color="m")
_ = g.ax_marg_x.hist(tips["total_bill"], color="b", alpha=.6,
                     bins=np.arange(0, 60, 5))
_ = g.ax_marg_y.hist(tips["tip"], color="r", alpha=.6,
                     orientation="horizontal",
                     bins=np.arange(0, 12, 1))
g.ax_marg_y.tick_params(labeltop=True)
g.ax_marg_y.grid(True, axis='x', ls=':')
g.ax_marg_y.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))

g.ax_marg_x.tick_params(labelleft=True)
g.ax_marg_x.grid(True, axis='y', ls=':')
g.ax_marg_x.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(4))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I meant to plot the yaxis and not the xaxis of the marginal plots, but I have managed to do that using tick_params options. Thank you it is now working!